# file selector in a qtablewidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get one cell in a QTableWidget to be a box with button at end"..." with file selector, but don't know how to change what kind of widget the cell is.

Answer (score 4):

To control the types of cells in a table, it's best to use the `QTableView` class. Then, by using `QItemDelegate` you can make some table cell a button, to which you may bind a signal that opens a dialog.

I recommend starting by reading about [delegate classes](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/model-view-delegate.html) in the Qt docs.